# I want to copy magento session data from database to files

Tags: magento-enterprise, session, customer-session, core-session

I want transfer magento session storage from database to files.

I want to know how to do this.

What i did is, download [BLOB - 3.6 KiB] file from database **core_session** table for session and rename it with sess_frontend_session_id like **sess_n7g9t1872co23p0btnbos921c4**

and then upload file to var/session but it's not working

Cart data is lost for **not logged in** customers.

Comment: Having same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally find the solution to transfer session data from database to files

You can run following script to transfer session data from database to files

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    $table = $resource->getTableName('core/session');

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;

    $session = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

    $filePath = 'var/session/';
    foreach ($session as $sess) {
        $file = $filePath.'sess_'.$sess['session_id'];
        $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $sess['session_data']);
        fclose($fp);
        chmod($file, 0777);
    }
?>
```